# meaning of this syntax: "if (!test(v))"

Tags: javascript, syntax

Is

```
if (!test(v))
```

the same as

```
if (test !== v)
```

?

If not, i'm just wondering what *if (!test(v))* means?

Comment: You take the result of `test(v)` and negate it.

Comment: The above 2 are not same and reasons are in the below answers.

Comment: why would you downvote a question?  smh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is a function, `v` is the parameter passed to the function. You're testing the result of the function:

```
if (!test(v))
```

Is the same as:

```
if (!!test(v) == false)
```

The `!!` will coerce the result to a boolean.

Comment: `undefined == false` is not the same as `!undefined == !false`. So if test(v) returns undefined your example won't work.